# Kafka ACL's preventing client connection

Tags: apache-kafka

I've gone through the trouble of setting up 2-way TLS authentication on my Kafka server. Currently, it's a proof-of-concept setup with only 1 broker (named "kafka-0").  I've confirmed that without ACL's, there is proper authentication happening as all clients with the appropriate trust/keystore (including their personal certificate signed by a self-signed CA) can connect and make/see posts on topics. The broker and client certificates include a SAN extension providing their FQDN (these are all hosted in a Kubernetes cluster, so I use their Kubernetes identifier "pod-name.[container-name].namespace.svc.cluster.local").  The hostname validation isn't preventing them from connecting, so I'm under the impression the certificate chain is valid using the Subject Alternative Name extension.  The setup for brokers and clients both for the truststore and keystores are as follows:

```
    broker:
    -------
    truststore:
     - CA Certificate (alias caroot)
    keystore:
     - CA Certificate (alias caroot)
     - Broker Key Pair (alias localhost)

    client{1/2}:
    ------------
    truststore:
     - CA Certificate (alias caroot)
    keystore:
     - CA Certificate (alias caroot)
     - Client{1/2} Key Pair (alias localhost)
```

However, my issue remains when ACL's are turned on. I've setup 2 client pods within my cluster named "client1" and "client2", each with their own signed certificate with the Distinguished Names of:

```
    client1 cert:
    -------------
    Owner: CN=client1,O={company},L={City},ST={State},C={Country}
    Issuer: CN={self-signed CA},O={company},L={City},ST={State},C={Country}
    // Has a SAN for its FQDN for hostname validation

    client2 cert:
    -------------
    Owner: CN=client2,O={company},L={City},ST={State},C={Country}
    Issuer: CN={self-signed CA},O={company},L={City},ST={State},C={Country}
    // Has a SAN for its FQDN for hostname validation
```

When there are no ACL's, like I mentioned previously, they are able to connect to `kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092` no problem.  I use the following client.properties file when connecting a consumer and producer:

```
    client.properties:
    ------------------
    client.id=client{1/2}
    group.id=client{1/2}-group

    security.protocol=SSL
    ssl.truststore.type=JKS
    ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore
    ssl.keystore.type=JKS
    ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/keystore
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
    ssl.truststore.password={password}
    ssl.keystore.password={password}
    ssl.key.password={password}
```

Using the following command, I'm able to setup a consumer and producer on each of the client pods:

```
    producer start-up:
    ------------------
    kafka-console-producer.sh \
      --producer.config /path/to/client.properties \
      --broker-list kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 \
      --topic client{1/2}

    consumer start-up:
    ------------------
    kafka-console-consumer.sh \
      --consumer.config=/path/to/client.properties \
      --bootstrap-server kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 \
      --topic client{1/2} \
      --group client{1/2}-group \
      --from-beginning
```

However, the issues begin when I setup ACL's for both `client1` and `client2` on the server.  I use the following commands to setup the server environment:

```
    kafka topics:
    -------------
    kafka-topics.sh \
      --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 \
      --create \
      --topic client1

    kafka-topics.sh \
      --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 \
      --create \
      --topic client2

    kafka-acls:
    -----------
    kafka-acls.sh \
      --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 \
      --add \
      --allow-principal "User:client1" \
      --topic client1 \
      --group client1-group \
      --consumer \
      --producer

    kafka-acls.sh \
      --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 \
      --add \
      --allow-principal "User:client2" \
      --topic client2 \
      --group client2-group \
      --consumer \
      --producer
```

With these commands run, I've created two topics named `client1` and `client2`. Each principled user `client1` and `client2` has  ACL's that allow them to READ, DESCRIBE, WRITE, and CREATE on their respective topic from any host.

The problem occurs when I've applied these ACLs.  When I attempt to create and connect a `client1` producer connecting it to the same `client1` topic (from the previous code snippet), it connects.  However, when I attempt to send a message to the topic, I receive the following errors:

```
    WARN [Producer clientId=client1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {client1=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    ERROR [Producer clientId=client1] Topic authorization failed for topics [client1] (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
    ERROR Error when sending message to topic client1 with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [client1]
```

From those errors, it doesn't seem like the ACLs are properly working.  "Not authorized to access topics: [client1]".  However, checking the logs from the Kafka broker, I see an oddity that may point to the Principal Builder being the cause of the failure:

```
    INFO Principal = User: is Denied Operation = Describe from host = {IP} on resource = Topic:LITERAL:client1 for request = Metadata with resourceRefCount = 1 (kafka.authorizer.logger)
```

That `User: ...` makes me think that the Principal Builder wasn't able to dissect the Common Name from the `client1` certificate and map it to a user on Kafka.  I have the `ssl.principal.mapping.rules` configuration value set in my `server.properties` file that essentially says "Grab the Common Name, ensure it's all lowercase, and use that as the User principal".  You can find that as well as other relevant `server.properties` settings below:

```
    server.properties
    -----------------
    
    allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true (this is just temporary)
    authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^CN=(.?*).*$/$1/L
    
    ssl.client.auth=required
    ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
    tls.client.auth=required
    tls.type=JKS
    ssl.keystore.type=JKS
    ssl.truststore.type=JKS
    ssl.key.password={the password}
    ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/broker/keystore
    ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/broker/truststore
    ssl.keystore.password={the password}
    ssl.truststore.password={the password}
```

I've tried all manner of Principal RULE for the Principal Builder.  I'm using the `DefaultKafkaPrincipalBuilder` and it's showing up in the broker logs as if it has started up. I'm not really sure what is the root cause of the issue, but my thinking is the Principal Builder isn't properly creating a Principal User from the client certificates.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it turns out that I shouldn't have trusted that the Kafka documentation would just give me a valid regex pattern.  My mistake for trusting documentation.

The issue was the PrincipalBuilder Rule I created:
`RULE:^CN=(.?*).*$/$1/L`
It was creating that `User:` principal which was my inclination.  After messing around with the principal Rule again, I was able to capture the entire principal I was looking for (e.g. `client{1/2}`).

Here was the rule (I'm sure I can write this a little better to incorporate more characters, but it works for my sample use case):
`RULE:^.*CN=([a-zA-Z0-9]*),.*$/$1/L`

Given a DN of `CN=client1,O={company},L={City},ST={State},C={Country}`, the resultant principal user is `client1`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your message but if you've found a mistake in the Kafka documentation, please report in via https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/issues or even better open a PR to fix it. Thanks